# Live video feeds in my own android application

Tags: android, video-streaming

I would like to develope a application for viewing a IP camera , DVR video feeds from my own application. Can anyone please tell me the best possible way to achieve it so that the delay is as minimum as possible. What all servers are required to stream the video the formats etc..

Answer (score 0):

androidfan , I believe you need to setup a media server to send & receive video streams.

[Red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/) will be a good option in your case.

[Red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/) is an Open Source Flash Server written in Java that supports: Streaming Video , Audio & RTMP protocols.